# does not display a particular id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to not display the id 49 and 50. I've been using the following query but it did not work

```
$tampil= mysql_query("SELECT comments,nama,kota,jwb FROM user where id='49','50'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the next:

```
$tampil= mysql_query("SELECT comments,nama,kota,jwb FROM user where id NOT IN ('49', '50')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` and `<>` where `<>` means *NOT EQUAL*

```
SELECT comments, nama, kota, jwb FROM user WHERE id <> '49' OR id <> '50'
```

Answer (score 0):

You said (Emphasis mine):

> I would like to **not** display the id 49 and 50.

if you want to **NOT** show those ids... then you need to skip on them, like so:

```
 SELECT comments, nama, kota, jwb FROM user WHERE id <> '49' AND id <> '50'
```

Emphasis on **AND**. Notice that if - for example - `id` is `49` then `id <> '49'` will be `FALSE` but `id <> '50'` will be `TRUE`.. and `FALSE OR TURE` is `TRUE`, leaving it pass. Instead you want to use `AND` because `FALSE AND TURE` is `FALSE` making sure that id will not appear.

For more clarity use NOT IN (as [fortegente's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261376/402022)):

```
 SELECT comments, nama, kota, jwb FROM user WHERE id NOT IN ('49', '50')
```

---

For the opposite effect, just apply [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
 SELECT comments, nama, kota, jwb FROM user WHERE id = '49' OR id = '50'
```

Or...

```
 SELECT comments, nama, kota, jwb FROM user WHERE id IN ('49', '50')
```

---

Note: I hope to clear confusion for the casual reader (really I bet some people don't read, I wonder why I care to write).